# Python Extract numbers after certain strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a data frame looks like following

```
import pandas as pd
page = ['A','B','C','D']
URL = ['aaa.bbb3333.ccc.de12345.dddd.cccc','ccc2222.ddd.aaa.ho16589.ddd','ddd16893.aaa.de59875','aaa15875.ccc.ddd.ho13532']
df = pd.DataFrame({'page':page,'URL':URL})
```

I want to create a column which extract numbers after either 'de' or 'ho'. Note the length of numbers might be different and the position of 'de' or 'ho' might be different as well.

My code looks like below:

```
import re
def extract_number(df,url):
    for url in df:
        if df[url].str.contains('de', na = False) == True:
            match = re.search('de:P(\d+)')
        elif df[url].str.contains('ho', na = False) == True:
            match = re.search('ho:P(\d+)')
        else:
            match = 'not found'
        print(match)

out = extract_number(df, 'URL')
```

It returns the error 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

Desired output should look like following:

```
import pandas as pd
page = ['A','B','C','D']
URL = ['aaa.bbb.ccc.de12345.dddd.cccc','ccc.ddd.aaa.ho16589.ddd','ddd.aaa.de59875','aaa.ccc.ddd.ho13532']
ID = ['12345','16589','59875','13532']
df = pd.DataFrame({'page':page,'URL':URL,'ID':ID})
```

Million thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.extract` with positive lookbehind:

```
df["num"] = df["URL"].str.extract(r"(?<=de|ho)(\d+)")

print (df)

#
  page                                URL    num
0    A  aaa.bbb3333.ccc.de12345.dddd.cccc  12345
1    B        ccc2222.ddd.aaa.ho16589.ddd  16589
2    C               ddd16893.aaa.de59875  59875
3    D           aaa15875.ccc.ddd.ho13532  13532
```

Comment: You need to delete the numbers from the URL as well

Comment: delete the numbers? what do you mean?

Comment: the resulting dataframe shoud have URLs without additional numbers exept the id (I GUESS)... So, instead of `aaa.bbb3333.ccc.de12345.dddd.cccc`, it should be this `aaa.bbb.ccc.de12345.dddd.cccc`

Comment: Hmm OP said _I want to create a column which extract numbers after either 'de' or 'ho'..._. Not sure if that has to do with removing numbers on the original URL.

Comment: Yes, you're right... but the result he/she is expecting doesn't have these numbers... anyway, good job :)

Comment: So sorry guys. That was a mistake. I forget to type in numbers in URL. Thanks!